# How to read a mailing list as RSS

Tags: php, rss, mailing

I'm subscribed in a mailing list that I use only as reference for developing and I'm trying to read it with my RSS client but the mailing list doesn't provide the RSS.

So I thought it should be a way to convert the mailing list to a RSS I was trying to find some php class to install it in my server but cant find anyone.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I painlessly receive mail in linux and feed it to Rails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/902771/how-do-i-painlessly-receive-mail-in-linux-and-feed-it-to-rails)

Answer (score 12):

[Nabble](http://nabble.com) and [Gmane](http://gmane.org) both archive mailing lists and provide RSS feeds. If it's a development mailing list there is a good chance it's already archived there. Otherwise you can have Nabble archive a mailing list. I'd do that before going through the pain of implementing your own solution.