# email2db open source alternative

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, email, open-source

please do you know of an open source alternative for 
[email2db](http://www.email2db.com/?source=adwords),

or some module in ruby or php that allows me to interact with emails,
I want to open a link from an email and send the data from the attachment to a mysql,

thank you very much!

Comment: Both PHP and Ruby have an IMAP class to interact with mailboxes, see http://php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php and http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/imap/rdoc/classes/Net/IMAP.html .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure postfix to send incoming mails to a certain script that parses it and stores data in your database:

[How do I painlessly receive mail in linux and feed it to Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902771/how-do-i-painlessly-receive-mail-in-linux-and-feed-it-to-rails?rq=1)

This way you can easily create your own scripts that handle incoming emails